# Move an ImageButton after onClick event

Tags: android, move, imagebutton

I have an imageButton inside a RelativeLayaut.
My imageButton is 300x350px and positioned outside the screen (on top) -300px onClick the button go down 300px and go back to the initial position when click again. The effect is like a popup window.

I could obtain this working code.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/pag1" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:drawingCacheQuality="high" android:layout_width="1024px"
android:layout_height="600px">
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton8" 
android:layout_width="300px" 
android:layout_height="350px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="720px" 
android:background="@drawable/popup" 
android:layout_marginTop="-300px">
</ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE

```
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
...

//activity declarations
protected static final int WIDTH = 300;
protected static final int HEIGHT = 350;
int count=0;
...

///click
    final ImageButton pop=(ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.imageButton8);
    pop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;

            if (count==1){  
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                lp.setMargins(720, -20, 4, 0);
                pop.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
            else{
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                lp.setMargins(720, -300, 4, 0);
                pop.setLayoutParams(lp);
                count=0;
            }
        }   
    });
```

NOW I wont to add a smooth transition to the final position. I think in a FOR cycle using a sleep function. Your HELP is welcome

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start with deciding which platform you are targeting as there is a new animation framework in Honeycomb. Have a look at [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html).

If however you are targeting pre-3.0 versions then the simplest way is to define your animation in anim.xml and load it in your activity by using `android.view.animation.AnimationUtils`. Then once you've set your new layout params on the view, simply call `public void startAnimation (Animation animation)` on the view and it will animate it for you. Two lines in Java and a few more in XML.

Take a look at [Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) too.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering, how can I make the image button move around so that it looks as if it's vibrating? For example, the way Apple apps move when you hold them down to delete them? I have been searching this for a few hours with no luck, I really appreciate your help!